# MySQL database query to do an exact match if available

Tags: mysql

I am using a mySQL database and have values in a table that look like this..

```
id | room  | name
----------------------
22 | 38    | john doe
4  | 837   | jane doe
94 | 993   | joe blogs
```

I am trying to write a query that will do an exact match on the ID if it exists

So if I search for `38 john doe` it will select row with id `22`

Similary, if I just search for `38` then it will match the same row

I have this so far...

```
SELECT id, room, name
FROM mytable
WHERE room
LIKE '%38%'
```

Which works great if I only search for the term `38` but if I search for a term that includes the number 38 like `38 john doe` then it does not work.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you do a search `Where room like '%38%'` then you will get results including when `room` is 238, 385, 4389, etc., so I'm not sure why you are doing that if you just want the exact match of `room = 38`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the fact that '38' and 'john doe' are in different columns, so you need to check both:

```
WHERE room = 38
  AND name = 'john doe'
```

*UPDATED* based on the comment from the OP:
You definitely did not describe your problem correctly. You need to provide more details as to the data structure (especially data type) and your input (especially where it's coming from).

If your `room` column contains a string (if it doesn't, comparing it with a string is useless`) then you can try doing

```
WHERE room = '38'
   OR room LIKE '38 %'
```

Anything more complex - and you should really not do it in mysql alone - you should parse your input in the language you're writing your application in, and then use the result of the parsing in your query.  In pseudo-code, that would look something like this:

```
Split input string into tokens; '38 john doe' -> ['38', 'john' 'doe']
Convert first token into number: '38' -> 38
Raise an exception if conversion failed (e.g. input was 'abc john doe')
Use result of conversion in your sql
```

Comment: I think I might not be describing things well. I don't care about the name column matching, only the room number. But if somebody enters a search term containing '38 john doe' then it does not match the room number

Comment: @jsmitter3, that would be a parsing issue, where you need to parse the search term into a different Where clause: `where room in ['38', 'john', 'doe']`. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: @computercarguy You certainly don't want to use that kind of search.  Yes, you'd need to parse your input string, but you would only use the first token in comparison.

Comment: @jsmitter3 In that case don't use a query to fix it - simply process your data and remove the name from the string _before_ you send it to the database. Are you perhaps looking for how to remove any character that isn't a number from a string?

Comment: @AleksG, it accommodates a search term like 'john doe 38', which is possible for a human to misinterpret any "requirements" for the room number to be typed in first.

Comment: @computercarguy If your room number is a numerical column, then doing `room in ('38', 'john', 'doe')` will result in an error.

Comment: @AleksG, that's true, but if the room is a nvarchar to accommodate room numbers like '38A' and 'Rosemont Hall', then it's a valid query.  Since the OP is trying a '%38%' query, I'd have to assume the column isn't numerical.